# Java Access Enum specific methods?

Tags: java, string, enums, return, getter

I have created an enum as so:

```
enum Types { hi, hello, bye }
```

I have added a getter inside each individual enum as so:

```
enum Types {
    hi {
        String test = "From hi";
        public String getString() {
        return test;
    },
    etc.
}
```

Except I cannot call "Types.hi.getString()".  Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Is this your code, seems to have a missing }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your enum class, define the method you want to access as `public abstract`.

Like so:

```
 enum Types {
      hi {
        public String getString() {
          return "From hi";
        }
      };

      public abstract String getString();
  }
```

As an alternative, let your enum class implement an interface:

```
public interface StringProvider {
     String getString();
}

public enum Types implements StringProvider {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method and field declarations should go inside the enum (i.e. Types). hi, bye and hello are instances of Types.

Answer (score -1):

You're not doing it exactly right.
Sun has a doc on how to include methods and fields in enums. Here [it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html) is.